# How do I view code in Visual Studio in Release Mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I change from debug to release mode in Visual Studio and the code is being optimized after debugging in Release Mode, can I see what the optimized code looks like? Or it is already a binary code that is optimized so Visual Studio itself doesn't optimize the code by rewriting it in C++, so there is no any C++ code that is my code but already rewritten for optimalization.

Comment: Open a file with code in it, a.k.a. source file.  Switch compiler to Release mode.

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiler that optimizes C++ by emitting optimized C++.  You may be interested in C++'s [phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Comment: The compiler's job is to translate C++ into machine code, not more C++. The kinds of optimizations that can be done for Release build are often things like unrolling loops, inlining calls, resequencing instructions, vectorization, removing unused code, and optimizing the stack by putting data in registers. Most of this has no representation in terms of useful C++. As the current answer indicates, you can view the program's disassembly, but be aware there might be a lot of it, and whether or not it is annotated will depend on your build settings.

Comment: @paddy Thanks for that, note added about configuring the necessary build settings in VS.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for both Debug and Release builds:

1. Set a breakpoint on the line(s) of interest.
2. Launch your program under the debugger (F5).
3. When your program breaks, right-click and select 'Go To Disassembly'.

But just to say, the code generated by the compiler in Release mode is not always easy to follow so be prepared for some surprises.

---

[Edit] As per @paddy's comment above, make sure that you compile your project with debugging information included, otherwise none of this will work properly:

`Project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format = Program Database (/Zi)`